# When mirroring a object in blender text texture on object get flipped on mirrored object

Tags: mesh, uv, normals, mirror-modifier

I have a right leg shoe with texture and want to mirror it on left side like shoe pair...But after mirroring the object the text logo is getting flipped on mirrored object. Any solution to this problem ??
here is the Screenshot of the problem
[image]

Comment: Of course its flipped, because it is mirrored :D it works the same way you look into the mirror. I guess you have to make a separate texture for that one, once you apply the mirror modifier

Answer (score 4):

Just apply your mirror and mirror your texture.

or...

use this:

[image]

check the "Mirror U" or/and "Mirror V" checkbox - depends on your setup.

without "Mirror U":

[image]

Comment: Its not working for me maybe I am doing it the wrong way
here is the screenshot
https://ibb.co/ZSGJhLb

Comment: Please provide your blend file. Looks like you have kind of rotation in it. But your texture isn‘t mirrored anymore. So now let’s face the next problem 

Comment: Very good you saved me from applying the mirror, thank you, what a small tip can save a ton of time

Comment: please click on the checkmark left of my answer if it helped you, thx